# Obtain statistics iteratively in R

Tags: r, loops

I have a dataframe with several variables. One of them is continous and the other one is categorical.

I want to obtain wilcoxon test between these two variables, which is basically a metric to compare the difference between two groups of samples.
This is really easy when you know which factors you want to compare.

For example, in the Arthritis dataset you have 5 variables (image below)

As we can see, the variable `Improved` has three levels `marked`, `some` and `none`.
We would like to see if there are differences between the patients `marked` and `none` for the variable `age`.

This is pretty straightforward, we would just need to create two vectors with the `age` of `marked` patients and with the `age`of `none` patients, and then apply wilcox.test.

However, I would like to create a script that allows you to automatically obtain all the `p-values` against a chosen factor of the variable.

So, for example, you would choose `None` and then iterate over the other factors of the variable and store the p-values.

Comment: You could use `pairwise.wilcox.test()` to perform tests for all combinations of a factor's levels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiest way to achieve this would be to just use
`stats::pairwise.wilcox.test()` to calculate all pairwise tests for a factor. Then
extract only the results of interest.

```r
multiple_wilcox <- function(response, factor) {
  pairwise.wilcox.test(response, factor, p.adjust.method = "none")$p.value[, 1]
}

# By default, tests are found against the reference level
with(iris, multiple_wilcox(Sepal.Length, Species))
#>   versicolor    virginica 
#> 8.345827e-14 6.396699e-17

# ... which can be changed with `relevel()`
with(iris, multiple_wilcox(Sepal.Length, relevel(Species, "virginica")))
#>       setosa   versicolor 
#> 6.396699e-17 5.869006e-07
```